# It does not give me exact button count in jQuery

Tags: jquery

It is not giving me exact button count in table as when i add one row in table and when i click on edit button it gives me 2 button counts where there is only one button in table and one more thing it is also gives me some pseudo error when i want to check wheather edit button clicked or not in table`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 1;
    $("#submit_Button").on('click', function() {
        var fname_Field = $("#fname1").val();
        var lname_Field = $("#lname1").val();
        var address_Field = $("#address1").val();

        if ($("#fname1").val() == null || $("#fname1").val() == "" && $("#lname1").val() == null || $("#lname1").val() == "" && $("#address1").val() == null || $("#address1").val() == "") {
            alert("Please fill the form");
        }

        $(".above_Info").append('<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td>' + fname_Field + '</td><td>' + lname_Field + '</td><td>' + address_Field + '</td><td><input type="button" name="edit" id="edit_Button" value="Edit"/></td></tr>');
        count++;
    });

    $(document).on('click', "input[type=button]", function() {
        alert("I am in edit button");
        var button_Count = $("input[type=button]").length;
        alert(button_Count);
        if ($("input[type=button]").is(":clicked")) {
            alert("I am in button");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.form {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#address1 {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#fname1,
#lname1 {
    margin-left: 9px;
}

#submit_Button {
    margin-left: 95px;
}

.above_Info {
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" class="form">
    First Name : <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname1" /><br /> 
    Last Name : <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname1" /><br /> 
    Address : <input type="text" name="address" id="address1" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit_Button" />
</form><br /><br /><br />
<table class="above_Info"></table>
```

Comment: what is the input type of `#submit_Button`

Comment: type button you can see below :)

Comment: oops I have not went down :) , So there nothing wrong it's giving count 2

Comment: It shows `2` because there is 2 buttons, the `Edit` and the `Submit`. The 'pseudo' error is because you're using a `:clicked` selector which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: also ID should be unique `edit_Button` this id will duplicate

Comment: how do i correct that error in pesudo

Comment: what's ur exact requirement ?

Comment: actully there are 3 text box in form so when i click on submit it should submit in table and when i click on any edit button in table for particular row it should reflect in form again for edit

Comment: anybody is there who can give me answer?? I can i check button is clicked or not in this code, it is giving me pseudo error

Answer (score 1):

you try to get the `last index` instead of using `count` like this and increment it ?

```
$(".above_Info> tbody > tr:last").find("td:first").text()+1
```